# Ruby and Cucumber Project Structure

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara, project-structure

How to structure ruby cucumber project such that actual code resides in one folder and test suite resides in another with single point of entry to invoke entire test suite. And to achieve that what other factors do I need to consider.

Comment: Create a directory/folder, open a cmd/terminal, and navigate to the newly-created directory.  Then run `cucumber --init`, and a features directory (containing step_definitions and support directories) will be created.  Then it's time to [RTM](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Table-Of-Content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily set up cucumber for use with rails by using the cucumber-rails gem https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails

Then in your Gemfile add

```
group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
end
```

Next you'll want to

```
bundle install
```

And then use the generator to set up cucumber in your rails app

```
rails generate cucumber:install
```

This will set up your cucumber code under the `features` directory in your app.

Then you can run your cucumber using

```
 ./script/cucumber
```